# Error regarding variable in Selenium TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng

I'm trying to run below code from IntelliJ but in turns an error (below). I just want to click a button on the website using a Xpath locator and adding an assertion to validate my test. What is the best approach to build such a simple test?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.List;

public class ButtonTest extends CommonScenario {

  private static WebDriver driver;

  @Test()
  public void button_test() {
    button b = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='Teleworking"));
  }
```

Error:

```
Error:(16, 5) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class button
      location: class selenium.ButtonTest
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `button` class. `driver.findElements` returns a list of `WebElement`

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements();
```

If you want a single element use `driver.findElement`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement();
```

Comment: Ok, I want to click that particular element (button) using below code. What's the solution for this?:
 `@Test()
  public void button_test() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Teleworking")).click();
  }`

Comment: @Fahri what is stopping you from doing it?

Comment: I forgot to mention sorry. I get following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at selenium.ButtonTest.button_test(ButtonTest.java:16) <18 internall calls>

Answer (score 0):

There is no class called button in order to initiate the object b with. Try WebElements.
So the method's code would be

```
public void button_test() {
List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='Teleworking"));
}
```

And note that you are using findElements and not findElement which would return a list of webelements and not a single webelement.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have single element with the xpath `"//button[text()='Teleworking"`. If so then update your script like below

```
 WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Teleworking"));
```

If you have more than one button with the same xpath as above then you need to handle it through List and in that case you can use below XPath.

```
List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='Teleworking"));
```